# Aggregated values depending on an other field

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table with a date-time and multiples propertied some on which I group by and some on which I aggregate, the query will be like get me revenue per customer last week.
Now I want to see the change between the requested period and the previous one so I will have 2 columns revenue and previous_revenue.

Right now I'm requesting the rows of the requested period plus the rows of the previous period and for each aggregated field I add a case statement inside which return the value or 0 if not in the period that I want.

That lead to as many CASE as aggregate fields but always with the same conditional statement.

I'm wondering if there is a better design for this use case...

```
SELECT
customer,
SUM(
  CASE TIMESTAMP_CMP('2016-07-01 00:00:00', ft.date) > 0 WHEN true THEN 
    REVENUE
  ELSE 0 END
) AS revenue,
SUM(
  CASE TIMESTAMP_CMP('2016-07-01 00:00:00', ft.date) < 0 WHEN true THEN 
    REVENUE
  ELSE 0 END
) AS previous_revenue

WHERE date_hour >= '2016-06-01 00:00:00'
AND date_hour <= '2016-07-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY customer
```

(In my real use case I have many columns which make it even more ugly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd suggest to refactor out the timestamps and precalculate the current and previous period for later use. This is not strictly necessary to solve your problem, though:

```sql
create temporary table _period as
    select
        '2016-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp as curr_period_start
      , '2016-07-31 23:59:59'::timestamp as curr_period_end
      , '2016-06-01 00:00:00'::timestamp as prev_period_start
      , '2016-06-30 23:59:59'::timestamp as prev_period_end
;
```

Now a possible design to avoid repetition of timestamps and `CASE` statements is to group by the periods first and then doing a `FULL OUTER JOIN` for that table on itself:

```sql
with _aggregate as (
    select
        case
          when date_hour between prev_period_start and prev_period_end then 'previous'
          when date_hour between curr_period_start and curr_period_end then 'current'
        end::varchar(20) as period
      , customer
   -- < other columns to group by go here >
      , sum(revenue)     as revenue
   -- < other aggregates go here >
    from
        _revenue, _period
    where
        date_hour between prev_period_start and curr_period_end
    group by 1, 2
)
select
    customer
  , current_period.revenue  as revenue
  , previous_period.revenue as previous_revenue
from
                (select * from _aggregate where period = 'previous') previous_period
full outer join (select * from _aggregate where period = 'current')  current_period

using(customer) -- All columns which have been group by must go into the using() clause:
                -- e.g. using(customer, some_column, another_column)
;
```